# Vector Subspace Test

Tags: vector-spaces

Hey can some help me with this textbook question I think it is a subspace I just want to be sure thanks

Let $R^{2\times2}$ denote the vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices, and let
$$
S =\left\{
\left[\begin{matrix}
a \space b \\ 
-b \space c \\
\end{matrix}\right]\mid a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$
Such that a b and c are Real numbers. Either show that S is a subspace of ${R^{2 \times 2}}$, or explain why it is not a subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phrasing isn't quite correct. $S$ can't be both a single matrix and a subspace; I think you mean that $S$ is the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices of a given form.

---

But you are correct that $S$ is a subspace, for if $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ is given and we choose two elements of $S$, we find that

$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ -b & c\end{array} \right) + \left(\begin{array}{cc} a' & b' \\ -b' & c'\end{array} \right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a + a' & b + b' \\ -(b+b') & c+c'\end{array} \right)$$

has the correct form and

$$ \alpha \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ -b & c\end{array} \right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \alpha a & \alpha b \\ -(\alpha b) & \alpha c\end{array} \right)$$

also has the correct form. Finally, $S \neq \emptyset$ since it contains the zero matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Additivity

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
a \space b \\ 
-b \space c \\
\end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix}
d \space e \\ 
-e \space f \\
\end{matrix}\right] =\left[\begin{matrix}
(a+d) \space (b+e) \\ 
(-b-e) \space (c+f) \\
\end{matrix}\right] =\left[\begin{matrix}
(a+d) \space (b+e) \\ 
-(b+e) \space (c+f) \\
\end{matrix}\right] \checkmark
$$
Scalarity:
$$
\lambda \left[\begin{matrix}
a \space b \\ 
-b \space c \\
\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}
\lambda a \space \lambda b \\ 
-\lambda b \space \lambda c \\
\end{matrix}\right]\checkmark
$$
Null:
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
0 \space 0 \\ 
-0 \space 0 \\ 
\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}
0 \space 0 \\ 
0 \space 0 \\ 
\end{matrix}\right] \checkmark
$$
Here we take for granted that $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under multiplication, and addition. So indeed $S$ is a subspace.

Comment: @downvote care to explain?

Comment: @downvote If this had been a homework problem-- I'd of probably not worked it through. Would you mind telling me what things I could rephrase?

Comment: You could, rather, have _not_ rephrased the OPs post to change your answer from wrong to $\hspace{1 in}$ right and Bongers' answer from right to slightly redundant. $\;$

Comment: @rickydemer feel free to change it back to the way it was. Bonger, feel free to remove the redundancy or change the op's question back to the way it was

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really easy way using the fact that kernels are subspaces (we just have to choose our map carefully).

Let $T\colon\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by $$T\left(\left[\begin{matrix}
w \space x \\ 
y \space z \\
\end{matrix}\right]\right)=x+y$$ which you can easily show is a linear transformation. It's also easy to see that $\ker T=S$ because $T(A)=0\iff x+y=0\iff x=-y$. The kernel of a linear transformation is a vector subspace of the domain and so $S$ is a subspace.

---

You could also use the fact that the image of a linear transformation is a subspace of the codomain.

Let $T\colon\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ be given by $$T(x,y,z)=\left[\begin{matrix}
x \space y \\ 
-y \space z \\
\end{matrix}\right]$$ which, again, is clearly linear and we see that $\mbox{Im }T=S$. Hence $S$ is a linear subspace.